# click a href link automatically on page load depending on hash location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in HTML/JS:

```
<a href="#customer_tickets" class="tabLink" onclick="LoadPage('/customer/editcustomer_tickets.php?customer=<?php echo $customer["sequence"]; ?>', '.EditCustomer');">Tickets</a>

if(location.hash) {
        //load the set hash here
}
```

when the a href is clicked, it runs the LoadPage function in JS to load a page into a div

when they are clicked it sets the hash location in the URL of the browser

i want to be able to check if the hash location is set when the page loads and if it is, then to click the correct a href automatically

how can i do this?

Comment: Why not try to load the page into the div if the location.hash is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the value of `location.hash` to identify the correct `a` element, then click it:

```
//Wait for the document to be ready
$(function() {
    //Check if we have a hash, if so try to click an element that links to it
    if (location.hash.length > 0) {
        $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').click();
    }
});
```